# How can I make iMovie delete videos from my iPhone after importing them?

Tags: iphone, imovie

In iPhoto, after you import images you can tell it to delete the files off of your phone. Is there a way to do this in iMovie?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can, but you can delete them using Image Capture!

Image Capture lives in your Applications folder and can show the contents of a camera (or your iPhone's camera roll) as a list, and you can manipulate it directly, including deleting some or all of it. I'd just pull up Image Capture after your import, and then sort by kind to isolate the movies, and delete the items you just imported.

Comment: This accomplishes what I want, especially if I drop the files into the iMovie Dropbox...

Comment: After latest update this doesn't work anymore (there's no longer a "delete" option in Image Capture)

Answer (score 0):

If the videos or photos are **only in iMovie** and not actually in iOS Photos (Camera Roll), you will be able to see those videos while you have any iMovie project open.

Just open or create any iMovie project and hit the plus button to browse through the media. You'll be able to find your photo/video there, press the Edit button on top and delete it.

If the videos or photos are in some of your iOS library, you might have to delete those in the corresponding iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Open up any project. OR start a new project by pressing "+" sign, select "create movie" at bottom of screen.
2. Press the "+" sign at the top of screen "to add video, photos or audio."
3. Press "Video".
4. Press "iMovie Media"
5. Select the video you want to delete
6. Select the trash can icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete videos from iMovie by deleting them from the camera roll, but you will loose all your videos that you have imported from iMovie. It means the videos in camera roll are the ones in iMovie. **But**, if you want to keep all the imported videos, just upload them and save them to Google Photos. Then you can delete them from iMovie but you will not see all the imported videos in the camera roll. If you want see your videos just go to Google Photos and download them to you phone or computer and save them.

Answer (score -1):

You go to your Photos and press on "photo" and `+` sign, then press `delete`.

Answer (score -2):

Go to the photos app, then albums, then videos ..... you will see your video there and can delete.

Comment: The question is how this can be done in iMovie.  Can you please edit your answer to address the question?